# Passing c++ variable to batch

Tags: c++, batch-file

I've a batch file like this :

```
set arg1=%1
do_something %arg1%
```

It works perfectly fine when called from cmd, but when I'm trying to execute it via c++ system call it won't work.

When I try something like

```
string a = "aaaaa.bat 123";
system(a.c_str());
```

it will call the bat file, but it won't receive 123 argument for some reason.

Comment: JFYI - [Why system() is evil](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/) (and what to use instead)

Answer (score 1):

Execute your batch file from a command shell like: `system("CMD.exe /C aaaaa.bat 123")`.